# How render text correctly inside a Div?

Tags: html, css

In the following example you can see that 'c' and 'x' going out from the div how to place correctly inside the div?

```css
.d {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left-width: 2px solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-top-width: 2px solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-width: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: 'white';
}
.controllContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.controls {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d " style="">
  test text
  <svg style="pointer-events: none;position: absolute;top: -2px;left: 70px;" width="40" height="34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polyline style="pointer-events:all;fill:white;stroke:#FF0000;stroke-width:2" points="0,0 40,17 , 0,34" stroke-linecap="round">

    </polyline>
  </svg>
  <div class="controllContainer">
    <div class="controls">c</div>
    <div class="controls">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `line-height` to the `.controls`.

```css
.d {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left-width: 2px solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-top-width: 2px solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-width: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: 'white';
}
.controllContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.controls {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  line-height: 9px; /* added here */
}
```

```html
<div class="d " style="">
  test text
  <svg style="pointer-events: none;position: absolute;top: -2px;left: 70px;" width="40" height="34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polyline style="pointer-events:all;fill:white;stroke:#FF0000;stroke-width:2" points="0,0 40,17 , 0,34" stroke-linecap="round">

    </polyline>
  </svg>
  <div class="controllContainer">
    <div class="controls">c</div>
    <div class="controls">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is something to do with `line-height`, so add `line-height: 0.3` to the `.controls`:

```css
.d {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left-width: 2px solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-top-width: 2px solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-width: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: 'white';
}
.controllContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.controls {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  line-height: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="d " style="">
  test text
  <svg style="pointer-events: none;position: absolute;top: -2px;left: 70px;" width="40" height="34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polyline style="pointer-events:all;fill:white;stroke:#FF0000;stroke-width:2" points="0,0 40,17 , 0,34" stroke-linecap="round">

    </polyline>
  </svg>
  <div class="controllContainer">
    <div class="controls">c</div>
    <div class="controls">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

You might need to tweak a little bit to get it right. Coz it works fine in Firefox, and shows like the above image in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

line-height = height of the area will work well..

```css
.d {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left-width: 2px solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-top-width: 2px solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-width: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: 'white';
}
.controllContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.controls {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d " style="">
  test text
  <svg style="pointer-events: none;position: absolute;top: -2px;left: 70px;" width="40" height="34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polyline style="pointer-events:all;fill:white;stroke:#FF0000;stroke-width:2" points="0,0 40,17 , 0,34" stroke-linecap="round">

    </polyline>
  </svg>
  <div class="controllContainer">
    <div class="controls">c</div>
    <div class="controls">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. But not sure why it isn't working in this case.

Comment: In snippet it works well. This case will works everywhere.

Comment: I checked in front of my eyes, it doesn't. Theoretically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

`Line-height` and `text-align` works perfectly fine. As text are not defined inside any tag we have to align it using line-height,

```css
.d {
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-left-width: 2px solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-top-width: 2px solid;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  border-bottom-width: 2px solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: 'white';
}
.controllContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.controls {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  line-height:7px;/*Add this*/
  text-align:center;/*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="d " style="">
  test text
  <svg style="pointer-events: none;position: absolute;top: -2px;left: 70px;" width="40" height="34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <polyline style="pointer-events:all;fill:white;stroke:#FF0000;stroke-width:2" points="0,0 40,17 , 0,34" stroke-linecap="round">

    </polyline>
  </svg>
  <div class="controllContainer">
    <div class="controls">c</div>
    <div class="controls">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```